# PHP Error Only on Windows Server

Tags: php, parsing, syntax-error, wamp, lamp

I don't know where to start with fixing this one. I have a dual boot server with Ubuntu and Windows. In Ubuntu, everything's working fine, but in Windows (using WAMP), I get mysterious PHP errors on some of my sites while others (using PHP) are working fine.

[Ubuntu screenshot http://newplayproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/screenshot-windows.jpg](http://newplayproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/screenshot-windows.jpg)

Because it's working perfectly in Ubuntu, I'm guessing there's not actually an error with my code, but I'm missing some PHP module on Windows. Any ideas?

In response to one of the comments, here's the contents of "loop-blog.php":

```
<?php
global $options;
foreach ($options as $value) {
if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); }
}
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<? if ($xs_enable_static_feature == "false") { ?>
    <? } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="Static Image" class="static-image" width="880" height="280" title="Static Image" />
<? } ?>
    <? if ($xs_disable_slider== "true") { ?>
    <? } else { ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'nivoslider' ) ?> 
<? } ?>
    <div id="main">
<h1>Latest Posts</h1>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); ?>
            <div class="post">
                <div class="postcontent">
            <?
            // Checks To See If, Thumbnails Are Disabled
            if ($xs_disable_thumbnails_archieve == "true") { ?>
            <?
            //If Not Disabled, Show Thumbnails
            } else { ?>
            <div class="postimg">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/functions/timthumb.php?src=<?php 
                    if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) {
                        echo $thumbnail[0]; 
                    } else {
                        $postimage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post-image', true);
                        if ($postimage) {
                            echo $postimage;
                        } else {
                            echo catch_that_image();
                        }
                    }
                    ?>&amp;h=<?php echo $xs_thumbnail_height ?>&amp;w=<?php echo $xs_thumbnail_width ?>&amp;s=1" width="<?php echo $xs_thumbnail_width ?>" height="<?php echo $xs_thumbnail_height ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
            </div><!-- /postimg -->  
            <? } ?>
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- End Post Content -->
                </div><!-- End Post -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
        <?php
            //Check For the Page Navi Plugin
            if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
                wp_pagenavi();
            //Show Default Navigation if Page Navi Is Not Installed
            } else { ?>
                <div class="paginate">
                    <div class="paginate-left"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts') ?></div>
                    <div class="paginate-right"><?php next_posts_link('Older Posts') ?></div>
                </div><!-- /paginate -->
            <? } ?>
</div><!-- End Main -->     
<?php get_sidebar(); ?> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You'll need to post your code and the errors you're getting instead of just screenshots.

Comment: Please post the contents of loop-blog.php.

Comment: Probably not because the file ends there. :) There must be an opening bracket or something *before* line 62.

Comment: oh you're right, I was just being a smart ass anyway.

Comment: Edit it into your question. And remove the working screenshot while you're on it, that one doesn't help.

Comment: Ok, I added the code from "loop-blog.php" and am deleting the working screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you don't have `short_open_tag` enabled on Windows, thus missing some of the PHP blocks.

Check the output of `phpinfo()` if `short_open_tag` is turned On. If it's not, enable it in your *php.ini* file.

Comment: Great! This completely solved the problem for one of my sites. I'm guessing there must be some other PHP blocks that still need to be enabled, because on another site I'm still getting this error: Notice: Undefined variable: description in [path] on line 17 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0004366672{main}( )[path]:0 20.0007369056include( '[path]' )..\[path]:3 30.0009373008include( '[path]' )..\[path]:2 " />

Comment: That is probably because on the Ubuntu server `error_reporting` is set to something like `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` while on your Windows installation the `& ~E_NOTICE` part is missing.

Comment: Great, that fixed yet more of the errors! Though I'm still running into one more, again, that's only appearing in Windows: "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in [path] on line 12". Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, more guesswork. ;) Either the database connection couldn't be established at all (e.g. wrong password) or there was a syntax error in the query (unlikely if it works elsewhere) or the data structure on your system is different from what's on the server. Look for the `mysql_query()` before and `echo` the parameter. Then run that query against your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this section:

```
<?php
    //Check For the Page Navi Plugin
    if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
        wp_pagenavi();
    //Show Default Navigation if Page Navi Is Not Installed
    } else { ?>
        <div class="paginate">
            <div class="paginate-left"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts') ?></div>
            <div class="paginate-right"><?php next_posts_link('Older Posts') ?></div>
        </div><!-- /paginate -->
    <? } ?>
```

It looks like maybe you don't have balanced `<?php` and `?>` PHP tags.

Not certain, but definitely something to check.

And definitely avoid the (obsolete, XML-incompatible) `<? ... ?>` "short tag" form, if at all possible.  It's definitely *not* something you want to use going forward.

IMHO...

Comment: This is true, but I note that the `<?=` form to echo is fully supported by PHP and is not affected by the `short_tags` configuration option.

Comment: I think that is true not before PHP 5.4.